# How to switch between multiple tabs with buttons in Dash and also how to reset a button after click once?

Tags: python-2.7, plotly-dash

I am looking to find a way to switch between multiple tabs by clicking buttons present inside the tabs. I am unable to find a way to reset a button after it is click once so the app won't fail if someone clicks the button multiple times.

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
import pandas as pd   
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output



app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1(' Analysis Tool'),
    dcc.Tabs(id='tabs-example', value='tab-0', children=[
        dcc.Tab(label='tab-0', value='tab-0'),
        dcc.Tab(id='tab1', label='tab-1', value='tab-1',children=[            
            html.Button('button 1', id='submit-val', n_clicks=0,
                    style={'width':185,'display':'inline-block','padding-right':80})
        ]),
        dcc.Tab(id= 'tab2', label='tab-2', value='tab-2',children=[            
            html.Button('button 2', id='submit-col', n_clicks=0,
                    style={'width':185,'display':'inline-block','padding-right':80})
        ]),
        dcc.Tab(id= 'tab3', label='tab-3', value='tab-3',children=[            
            html.Button('button 3', id='submit-rev', n_clicks=0,
                    style={'width':185,'display':'inline-block','padding-right':80})
        ]),
        dcc.Tab(id='tab4', label='tab-4', value='tab-4')                     
    ]),
    html.Div(id='tabs-example-content') 
])    

@app.callback(Output('tabs-example', 'value'),
              [Input('submit-val', 'n_clicks'),
              Input('submit-col', 'n_clicks'),
              Input('submit-rev', 'n_clicks')])
def on_click_val(click1, click2, click3):

    if click1>click2 and click2>=click3:
        return "tab-2"
    elif click2>=click1 and click2>click3:
        return "tab-3"
    elif click3>=click1 and click3>=click2:
        return "tab-4"
    elif click1 == 0 and click2 == 0 and click3 == 0:
        return "tab-0"
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of Dash Callback Context, in this case, to get the ID of the element clicked since your purpose here is to identify which button was clicked and not how many times it was clicked.

```
@app.callback(Output('tabs-example', 'value'),
              [Input('submit-val', 'n_clicks'),
              Input('submit-col', 'n_clicks'),
              Input('submit-rev', 'n_clicks')])
def on_click_val(click1, click2, click3):

    btn = dash.callback_context.triggered[0]["prop_id"].split(".")[0]

    if btn == "submit-val":
        return "tab-2"
    elif btn == "submit-col":
        return "tab-3"
    elif btn == "submit-rev":
        return "tab-4"
    else:
        return "tab-0"
```